# Fazer condição if com split

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a precisar fazer uma condição, onde verifico se numa `input` o utilizador introduziu o carácter `.`.

Para tal estou a fazer um `if` onde faço `split` com valor da minha input.

```
if (idCliente.split('.')[1].length > 0)
```

Se a `input` tiver `.` corre tudo bem, mas caso não exista tenho erro javascript no `.length` (diz que é undifined) e não corre o resto da função.

Fiddle
[aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/ZN5Ux/)

Existe outra forma de fazer a condição?

Comment: Onde vai buscar `idCliente` pode colocar esse código?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se o split encontrar um `.` então você quer medir o length do `idCliente`, **não o tamanho da string** do segundo elemento da possível array. Tente assim:

```
idCliente.split('.').length > 1
```

Ou seja, verificar se o split gera um array com mais do que um elemento.

---

Exemplo de codigo:

```
var stringA = 'abcde';
var stringB = 'abc.defgh';

console.log(stringA.split('.').length); // 1 (array)
console.log(stringB.split('.').length); // 2 (array)
console.log(stringB.split('.')[1].length); // dá 5, porque está a medir a string
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2jy6/)

Comment: É mesmo isso. Estava a verificar se existia dados na `[1]` do meu array. Daí o meu erro. Thanks @Sergio